# VS Code - Go: Prevent removal of test coverage markings after save

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, code-coverage, go-testing

I'm using VS Code for a Go project. I have it configured to show the code coverage with gutter markings after I run the tests.

The issue I'm having is that if I make any changes to a file in the package, and then save it, VS Code then removes all of the coverage markings from all package files. I've gone through all of the Go settings and cannot find one that prevents this from happening.

There are options to re-run the tests on every save, which would then show the new coverage markings, but that's not feasible for this package because the tests take relatively long to run.

I'd like to find a way for it to keep the most recent test coverage markings when I save a file, instead of removing them all. Is this possible?